# why TCP/IP are mentioned together

Tags: tcp, ip

Transmission Control Protocol and Internet Protocol are two different protocols.
then why they are always mentioned together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official name for TCP/IP is *Internet Protocol Suite*. TCP/IP is a shorthand used by its authors to refer to this new iteration of a standard based on a previous protocol simply called TCP (for *Transmission Control Program*), so one may infer that the new acronym was meant to differentiate from the latter.

Quoting the Wikipedia entry:

> In May 1974 the Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers
>   (IEEE) published a paper titled "A Protocol for Packet Network
>   Intercommunication." The paper's authors, Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn,
>   described an internetworking protocol for sharing resources using
>   packet-switching among the nodes. A central control component of this
>   model was the **Transmission Control Program** that incorporated both
>   connection-oriented links and datagram services between hosts. The
>   monolithic Transmission Control Program was later divided into a
>   modular architecture consisting of the **Transmission Control Protocol**
>   at the *connection-oriented layer* and the **Internet Protocol** at the
>   internetworking (datagram) layer. The model became known informally as
>   TCP/IP, although formally it was henceforth called the Internet
>   Protocol Suite.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Historical_origin

Answer (score 1):

They are the protocols used by the Internet Protocol Suite and are always mentioned together because they both are necessary to transmit data over the internet.

From wikipedia: "TCP provides reliable, ordered and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets between programs running on computers connected to a local area network, intranet or the public Internet." and "IP,[...] has the task of delivering packets from the source host to the destination host solely based on the IP addresses in the packet headers."

When you need to send a message from one computer to another the TCP is responsible to break this message in smaller packages and leave the rest of work to IP, that takes care of deliver these smaller groups of data to the correct destination. In the other side, when the other computer receives the packages, TCP assembles them to get the original message.